# Linq To Entities DayOfYear Alternative for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I need to perform a grouping based on the week number in a year using Linq to Entities connecting to a MySQL database. My current query looks like.

```
entities.GroupBy(t => t.StartTime.Year + "/" + 
    (int)Math.Floor((double)(t.StartTime.DayOfYear - 1) / 7.0))
```

This however doesn't work as Entity Framework cannot map DayOfYear correctly. Is there any
way I can achieve this, still using Linq to Entities.

I am using Entity Framework 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I cant. Not easily.

So I have wrote a stored procedure that does the heavy lifting and used the MySQL built in function DAYOYEAR.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `SqlFunctions.DatePart` static method:

```
entities.GroupBy(t => t.StartTime.Year + "/" + 
    (int)Math.Floor((double)(SqlFunctions.DatePart("dy", t.StartTime.DayOfYear)) / 7.0))
```

But I'm not sure it will work with MySQL database.

Comment: [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) is often overlooked or not known about. Its a great set of tools.

Comment: Sadly I can't use SqlFunctions as I am using a MySQL database via the MySQL Connector.